# How to use .not() to select all but one element inside body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck on a basic `.not()` method in jQuery. I can't manage to select all element but one. Using `.not()` seems like the right thing though.

Any hints?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').not($('#exclude')).click(function() {
    console.log('HELLO');
  })
})
```

```css
#container {
  background: red;
  padding: 2vh;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

#exclude {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    Print Hello when click
    <p id="exclude">
      DO Nothing when click
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I removed the strange `jQuery() ` construct

Comment: From what I understand, you're actually interested in excluding one element _and its children_. The proper approach is in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Even though `not()` works fine if used correctly, the click event will still propagate up the tree. You need this: https://jsfiddle.net/z3yabxLf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `event.target` like this:

```
if(event.target.id === "exclude")
    return;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').click(function(event) {
  if(event.target.id === "exclude")
    return;

    console.log('HELLO');
  })
})
```

```css
#container{
  background: red;
  padding: 2vh;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

#exclude {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="container">
Print Hello when click
<p id="exclude">
DO Nothing when click
</p>
</div>
</body>
```